# Is there a builtin ctypes equivalent in perl?

Tags: perl, shared-libraries

In python there is ctypes, which allow me to load and call libraries.
Is there an equivalent in perl?

The reason I want to do this, is that I am working on a closed platform where I cannot install any modules, but there is an abundance of shared libraries.

Such equivalent must of course be native for perl...

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In Perl, this is called [XS](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call functions in shared libs I suggest that you take a look at Inline::C, https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::C. There is a cookbook, https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::C-Cookbook, for getting started.

There also were some attempts to use libffic from Perl, but I don't know how far these went.